# Topology of the space of hermitian positive definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, topological-vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{H}_n \mathbb{C}$ be the set of hermitian $n \times n$ complex matrices. This set carries the structure of a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ under  usual addition. It also inherits the standard euclidean topology from $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Let $\mathcal{P}$ denote the subset of $\mathcal{H}_n \mathbb{C}$ of positive definite matrices and give it the subspace topology.

My question is: is $\mathcal{P}$ locally compact?

What I understand: $\mathcal{P}$ is closed under linear combination with positive coefficients, in particular it is closed under addition, multiplication by a positive scalar and is convex. In dimension $1$ it is just $]0,+\infty[$, so the answer is yes. My feeling is that the answer should be yes in higher dimensions as well, since $\mathcal{P}$ is a kind of "cone" in a real vector space, but I can't provide a rigorous proof of this.

Comment: I think this reasoning would apply to every subset of a metric space, but $\mathbb{R}$ has already some subset which is not locally compact, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$. The point is that the intersection of the unit ball with the subspace need not be compact.

Comment: But my question was about $\mathcal{P}$, which is not. See my comment to your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** I think that the first answer below is more efficient and easier to write. Nevertheless, I have added a more concrete approach which might be closer to what you were after.

**By some sort of transitivity:** recall that every open or closed subset of a [locally compact space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) is a locally compact space with the induced topology. We will use both, for open and for closed.

I consider every space here equipped with the topology induced by the Euclidean norm of $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Hence every space is Hausdorff. This is good to know, even though your question does not specifically ask about this aspect.

Like every finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is locally compact when equipped with the topology induced by any norm.

Clearly, $\mathcal{H}_n^+\mathbb{C}$, the set of positive semidefinite matrices, is closed in the locally compact $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. So $\mathcal{H}_n^+\mathbb{C}$ is a locally compact space.

Now $\mathcal{P}=\{A\in \mathcal{H}_n^+\mathbb{C}\;;\det A>0\}$. By continuity of the determinant, it follows that $\mathcal P$ is open in the locally compact $\mathcal{H}_n^+\mathbb{C}$. Hence $\mathcal P$ is a locally compact space. QED.

**Parametrized alternative:** fix $A_0$ hermitian definite positive, and denote $\{t^0_1,\ldots,t_n^0\}$ its (positive) eigenvalues. Now let $\epsilon:=\min t_j^0/2>0$. Then denote $U_n$ the unitary group and $\mathcal{H}_n^{++}$ the cone of positive definte hermitian matrices. Now consider the map
$$
\phi:U_n\times \prod_{j=1}^n[t_j^0-\epsilon,t_j^0+\epsilon]\longrightarrow \mathcal{H}_n^{++}
$$
which sends $(U,t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ to $U\mbox{diagonal}\{t_1,\ldots,t_n\}U^*$. Since $U_n$ is compact, the domain is compact. And since $\phi$ is continuous, the range of $\phi$ is a compact subset of $\mathcal{H}_n^{++}$ containing $A_0$. So it only remains to check that this is a neighborhood of $A_0$ in $\mathcal{H}_n^{++}$. To that aim, note that it contains
$$
\phi(U_n\times \prod_{j=1}^n(t_j^0-\epsilon,t_j^0+\epsilon))\ni A_0
$$
i.e. the set of hermitian definite positive matrices with spectrum $\{t_1,\ldots,t_n\}$ such that, up to a permutation, $|t_j-t_j^0|<\epsilon$ for every $j=1,\ldots,n$. By [continuity of polynomial roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/continuity-of-the-roots-of-a-polynomial-in-terms-of-its-coefficients) over $\mathbb{C}$ applied to the characteristic polynomial, this is open in  $\mathcal{H}_n^{++}$. QED.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** First, as $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is Hausdorff, so is $\mathcal{P}$.

Second, let $B(A,r)$ denotes the ball centred at a matrix $A$ with radius $r$ in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $\bar{B}(A,r)$ its closure. Since eigenvalues are continuous functions of matrix entries, for any $P\in\mathcal{P}$, there exists $r>0$ such that $B(P,r)\cap(\mathcal{H}_n \mathbb{C})\subset\mathcal{P}$. Therefore, for all $\varepsilon\in(0,r)$, the closure of $B(P,\varepsilon)\cap\mathcal{P}$ in $\mathcal{P}$ is simply $\bar{B}(P,\varepsilon)\cap\mathcal{P}=\bar{B}(P,\varepsilon)\cap(\mathcal{H}_n \mathbb{C})$, which is closed and bounded and hence compact in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. As [compactness is an intrinsic property of a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241798/compactness-across-induced-topological-spaces), $\bar{B}(P,\varepsilon)\cap\mathcal{P}$ is also compact in $\mathcal{P}$. Furthermore, $\bar{B}(P,\varepsilon)\cap\mathcal{P}$ has a non-empty interior ($B(P,\varepsilon)\cap\mathcal{P}$). So, it is a compact neighbourhood in $\mathcal{P}$.

In other words, $\mathcal{P}$ is a Hausdorff space such that its every member is contained in a compact neighbourhood. Hence $\mathcal{P}$ is locally compact.

Comment: I'm fine with this. After all it's a real vector space. But my question was about the topological subspace of positive definite hermitian matrices. This is not a vector subspace, nor a closed subspace, hence my doubts.

Comment: @Lor Thanks. I am talking about topological subspace, *not* vector subspace. (Why would you think I was talking about vector subspace?) But I have overlooked the keyword "positive definite", so I thought you only meant Hermitian matrices. I'll see if the answer can be fixed. If not, I'll delete this answer.

Comment: This is very straightforward, thanks! But I think we have to use that $\mathcal{P}$ is an open subspace in a closed one as @julien does in the answer above. Otherwise we can't guarantee that a subspace which happens to be compact in the ambient topology will also be compact in the subspace topology. Am I wrong? I don't want to be too pedantic but I think this is the key point.

Comment: I mean that $B(P,\varepsilon) \cap \mathcal{P}$ is of course an open neighborhood of $P$ in $\mathcal{P}$ and is contained in $\bar{B}(P,\varepsilon) \cap \mathcal{P}$ which is compact in $C^{n\times n}$. But I can't conclude from here that it is also compact in $\mathcal{P}$ if I don't know something more about the topology of $\mathcal{P}$.

Comment: @Lor A set that is compact in a superspace is also compact in a subspace. (In fact, compactness is an intrinsic property of a set. [The compactness of a set depends only on the topology of itself](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241798/compactness-across-induced-topological-spaces). You may speak of the compactness of a set without making any reference to its proper superspace.)